# Navigating HTML in VBA - unreliable code issue

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I've written code that navigates to a specific website (http://www.boxofficemojo.com/) and then copies / pastes a movie title from a spreadsheet into the search bar to search for that title and open up its individual movie page ((in the first case it is "Rogue One: A Star Wars Story).  This will ultimately be used to scrape data from this website for the 200 movies in my spreadsheet

My problem is the following.  When I step through this code manually it works reliably and as intended.  When I run it automatically (f5) it does not work reliably - it may work once but always derails and ultimately navigates me to the wrong webpage.  Even more strangely, if I set a breakpoint to the very last line of code, and then step through that last line, it works.  I cannot figure out why this is.  Code is below, any ideas would be much appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

'Start new subroutine
Sub FilmScraper()

'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim MovieCount As Integer  'counter

Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer 
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim oSearch As HTMLDivElement
Dim SearchElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim oResult As Object, Element As Object, myLink As Object

'Counting the number of titles to search for (will eventually be my main loop)
Sheets("2016").Select
MovieCount = 200

'open IE and navigate to box office mojo homepage
With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/"
        Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    Set Doc = objIE.Document
End With

'search for 1st title name in excel sheet
Set oSearch = objIE.Document.forms("searchbox").elements("q")
    oSearch.Value = Sheets("2016").Range("c3").Value
    objIE.Document.forms("searchbox").getElementsByTagName("input")(1).Click

Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
Loop

'open title page in box office
Set Doc = objIE.Document
Set oResult = Doc.getElementById("body").getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each Element In oResult
    If Element.outerHTML Like "*/movies/?id=*" Then
        Set myLink = Element
        Exit For
    End If
Next Element

objIE.Navigate myLink

'Scrape website and paste into excel (TBD)
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i rewrote your code a little

it works without hickup with a list of 5 movies

```
Rogue One: A Star Wars Story
happy death day
marshall
the foreigner
the snowman
```

place movie list starting at cell C3  .... adjust code to your liking for movie list

```
Option Explicit

'   ref
'     Microsoft HTML Object Library
'     Microsoft internet controls

Sub FilmScraper()

    'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim MovieCount As Integer  'counter

    Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim oSearch As HTMLDivElement
    Dim SearchElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim oResult As Object, Element As Object, myLink As Object

    'Counting the number of titles to search for (will eventually be my main loop)

    'Sheets("2016").Select ' this line does not do anything useful

    MovieCount = 200
    MovieCount = 5      ' test with 5 movies

    'open IE and navigate to box office mojo homepage
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/"
        Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

    Set Doc = objIE.Document

    Dim aaa As Range
'   For Each aaa In Sheets("2016").Range("c3").Resize(MovieCount)
    For Each aaa In ActiveSheet.Range("c3").Resize(MovieCount)

        'search for title name in excel sheet
        Doc.forms("searchbox").elements("q").Value = aaa.Value
        Doc.forms("searchbox").getElementsByTagName("input")(1).Click

        Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'open title page in box office
        Set Doc = objIE.Document
        Set oResult = Doc.getElementById("body").getElementsByTagName("a")
        For Each Element In oResult
            If Element.outerHTML Like "*/movies/?id=*" Then
                Set myLink = Element
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Element

        objIE.Navigate myLink

        Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'Scrape website and paste into excel (TBD)

        Set Doc = objIE.Document
        Set oResult = Doc.getElementsByClassName("mp_box")(1).getElementsByClassName("mp_box_content")
        aaa.Offset(0, 2).Value = oResult(0).innerText   ' put result in second cell to right of movie name


    Next aaa
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you!!  I have a bit of work to do scraping the exact HTML elements that I want but this is a huge help.  I appreciate it!